# VBA: Non exclusive ENUM or Ignore Type 13 error?

Tags: vba, enums, intellisense

I want a list of possible values to show up when I call a function func1. I found a way to achieve this in VBA via ENUM, but that doesn't work in a worksheet. So I've created a function e that will convert certain strings into the right enum value. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to call this function func1 with either a string or the enum value without getting an error or losing functionality. Here's what I've got so far:

```
Enum eLanguages
    evEnglish = 2
    evItalian = 3
    'and so on
End Enum

Function e(vString)
Select Case vString
    Case "english", "eng", "en", "e"
        e = evEnglish
    Case "italian", "italien", "it", "i"
        e = evItalian
    Case Else
        e = vString '(= will keep the value if it's already a number)
End Select
End Function
```

Option 1: Shows the list of possible values when typing in VBA, but won't work for string inputs

```
Function func1(var As eLanguages)
func1 = e(var)
End Function

Sub test1()
MsgBox func1(evEnglish)     'Will result in 2 (through the enum and the e function)
MsgBox func1("e")           'Type 13 error
End Sub
```

Option 2: Gives the right result but I don't get the list of possible values within VBA

```
Function func2(var)
func2 = e(var)
End Function

Sub test2()
MsgBox func2(evEnglish)     'Will result in 2 (through the enum and the e function)
MsgBox func2("e")           'Will result in 2 (through the e function)
End Sub
```

Note: Calling either of the two functions like this will give the right result, but obviously I'm not keen on having to write e() everytime I call the function:
    `MsgBox func1(e("e"))`

So do you have any suggestions on how to ignore the Type 13 error or how to include an "any string allowed" option in the ENUM declaration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `eLanguages`? You need to explain what you are doing more. There seems to be missing puzzle pieces.

Comment: Sorry, eLanguages is the enumeration.

Comment: Okay -- what is `e`? Since your question is about what happens when you call `e` in a certain way, it is almost impossible to answer without knowing what `e` actually is.

Comment: I edited the original post. "E" simply assigns one of the enum values if instead of the enum value a string is handed to the function. The point is to give the user several options to choose the language without having to look up the code for the exact wording.

Comment: why not have `e` return a string if that is what you want? The elements of enums are just aliases for integers (aliases to be used by the VBA programmer, not someone using the Excel application), so returning `evEnglish` *is* returning 2.

Comment: The one thought that occurs to me would be to add a second, *optional*  argument to func1 you can use to pass the literal string. And add an entry to the Enum for evOther. In your Select Case test for evOther and have func1 return the second parameter (the literla string) in this case instead of the Enum...

Comment: @John Coleman: That is what I will do if there's no other solution. But I would like to have both options, that is the string solution when working on the worksheet, and the enum solution when I'm writing code. And  really because of the "popup" (or whatever you call it) when calling a function in the editor.

Comment: @Cindy Meister: Interesting thought. The original function has some more arguments, though, so it would get reeeeaaaally long.

Answer (score 0):

@CinyMeister 's idea is interesting. A slight variation -- make *both* arguments optional and use `if - then - else`, together with the `IsMissing` function to merge the two arguments back into one:    Function func3(Optional x As eLanguages, Optional y As String)
        Dim var As Variant
        If IsMissing(x) Then

```
        var = y
    Else
        var = x
    End If
    func3 = e(var)
End Function

Sub test()
   MsgBox func3(evEnglish)
   MsgBox func3(, "it")
End Sub
```

Even with a large number of parameters, this sort of thing will work -- when you invoke the function in the VBA editor you can tab through the options by repeatedly pressing the comma key. Parameters that are given by enumerations will evoke intellisense drop-downs. Other parameters will hopefully have descriptive names.

Answer (score 0):

I just had another idea, but I don't think it would work as a superelegant solution either.

I could have 2 functions, one for Excel, one for VBA. Like that:

```
Function funcV(var As eLanguages)
funcV = SOMETHING
End Function

Function funcE(var)
funcE= funcV(e(var)) '(which is "SOMETHING")
End Function
```

The question is whether I would remember which of my many functions have a sister function. There's no way to capture the Type 13 error as an "on error" event and redirect automatically, is there?